# What is the history of the concept of more than 2 genders?

Tags: races

How has this issue addressed? How was reproduction capable between the 3 or more genders?

What are the first instances where a race with more than 2 genders occurred?

I know of instances when there was 1 gender. A [neuter race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outcast_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) in Star Trek where the species chose to remove the sexuality from themselves.

I haven't however, seen any times when they try to introduce the concept of more than 2.

Comment: Comments on the close votes are welcome and encouraged...

Comment: I just got here, but I suspect the close votes are because you're basically asking for a *list*, not a single specific answer.

Comment: I'm not asking for a list. I'm just asking how it's been addressed if it has been. 1 correct answer will answer my question.

Comment: The is a degree to which *"Has it been done"* for a case like this suggest you haven't done much research (so far we have books back to the 50s, and a couple of different TV shows). I'm still trying to place the passing reference I recall to a five-gendered race (though this may have been a joke). As a side note, it is pretty trivial for a author to say *"you know the whosists? They have <N> genders."*, without have thought through the biology or the sociology.

Comment: Even if you don't ask for a list, that's what this question will generate, since it's so open-ended. (Also see [this section of the the FAQ](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).) Perhaps asking about the history of the concept would yield better answers? Right now, it's generating answers that are pretty random.

Comment: @neilfein ok, I'll try that.

Comment: As originally formulated, this question was a prime example of a “list question” that the [FAQ] prohibits: “the following types of questions are off-topic here: Questions calling for a list of works, authors, …: *What are all the books that have X? Who wrote about topic Y?*” As usual, the answer is “yes, lots”. And [TV Tropes has a list](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExtraParentConception) which isn't nearly complete.

Comment: Personally I think lists are OK, but in such cases it should be a CW. So far no answers have dealt with "the history of" or "origin of" the concept.

Comment: It comes from high school biology. Cellular mitosis begat multicellular, organisms begat cellular meisos and sexual reproduction, begat colonies with mostly sterile members (a third gender of sorts). It's not too big a leap to wonder what the next innovation will be. (It will be genetic engineering, not 3 fertile genders.)

Comment: Bujold's Vorkosigan books have genetically-engineered hemaphrodites...

Comment: There is a whole Wikipedia article on this: "third gender". At the least please consult Wikipedia before asking here.

Comment: @markbeadles I asked this in September and I did do research before asking. And I was asking in terms of science fiction about the history of civilizations with more than 2 genders, not factual science.

Comment: Ooh, sorry.  Didn't notice the date for some reason. The wiki article does have a section on art and literature, is why I brought it up.

Comment: Incredibly, with so many answers and comments, nobody seems to have mentioned William Tenn's ["Venus and the Seven Sexes"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40820)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concept of a third sex is as old as writing. In Greek myth there's the figure of [Hermaphroditus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermaphroditus). In the [Sumerian creation myth](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/cgi-bin/etcsl.cgi?text=t.1.1.2), the goddess Ninmah creates an intersex human from clay:

> Sixth, she fashioned one with neither penis nor vagina on its body. Enki looked at the one with neither penis nor vagina on its body and gave it the name Nibru [perhaps = *eunuch*], and decreed as its fate to stand before the king.

The idea recurs in other ancient cultures; see Wikipedia's [third gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_gender#History) article for many more examples.

A few notable early examples in science fiction:

In [*A Voyage to Arcturus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Voyage_to_Arcturus) by David Lindsay (1920) some of the characters belong to a third sex:

> Nowadays there are men and women, but in the olden times the world was peopled by *phaens*. I think I am the only survivor of all those beings who were then passing through Faceny's mind.

The Last Men in Olaf Stapledon's novel [*Last and First Men*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_and_First_Men) (1930) have many sexes, though these are apparently organized into "male" and "female" sexes:

> The traveller would recognize among us unmistakable sexual features, both of general proportions and special organs. But it would take him long to discover that some of the most striking bodily and facial differences were due to differentiation of the two ancient sexes into many sub-sexes. Full sexual experience involves for us a complicated relationship between individuals of all these types. Of the extremely important sexual groups I shall speak again.

In [*That Hideous Strength*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Hideous_Strength) (1945) by C. S. Lewis there's a cryptic reference to the "Seven Genders":

> The three gods who had already met in the Blue Room were less unlike humanity than the two whom they still awaited.  In Viritrilbia and Venus and Malacandra were represented those two of the Seven Genders which bear a certain analogy to the biological sexes and can therefore be in some measure understood by men.  It would not be so with those who were now preparing to descend.  These also doubtless had their genders, but we have no clue to them.  These would be mightier 
>   energies: ancient eldils, steersmen of giant worlds which have never from the beginning been subdued into the sweet humilations of organic life.

Lewis didn't expand upon this, perhaps because he believed that it would be impossible to convincingly imagine a new sex. In [a 1943 letter](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Q7f3NuXV0UUC&pg=PT1098) he wrote, "Try to imagine a [new primary color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrachromacy), a [third sex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex), a [fourth dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space), or even a [monster that does not consist of existing animals stuck together](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exotic_alien_species). Nothing happens." (This now seems rather defeatist. Maybe he should have tried harder.)

Answer (score 8):

The [*Star Trek: Enterprise*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/ENT) episode ["Cogenitor"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cogenitor_%28episode%29) introduces a race called the [Vissians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vissian) who have 3 genders: male, female, and [cogenitor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cogenitor):

> The cogenitor does not pass on genetic material to the offspring they help create; Dr. Phlox suggested that they may supply an enzyme during the sex act which facilitates conception.

Answer (score 8):

Isaac Asimov's *The Gods Themselves* has a three-gendered race.

Raphael Carter's short story "Congenital Agenesis of Gender Ideation" concerns the revelation of a number of different human genders.

A theatre troupe including SF author Geoff Ryman presented an improvised piece at the 1991 Edinburgh Festival called USEXCO that concerned the creation and marketing of two additional human genders.

Comment: Asimov also put in a lot of detail into the biology of his three-gendered race to show how they are all involved in the reproductive process (although, not the mechanical aspects).

Answer (score 7):

They show up from time to time.

Ian Banks' *The Player of Games* features a three gendered pan-human race.

Niven's Puppeteers are likewise three gendered (though one could argue about this as the bearing gender is strictly a separate species).

Le Guin's *The Left Hand of Darkness* features a human race that lives as neuters except during brief periods during which they take on one or the other gender (but not always the same one), which could be construed as three genders if you wanted to.

Comment: Ooops, it's "Ian M. Banks", not "Back".  ;-)

Comment: Yes it is. Typing too fast and off the cuff.

Comment: Just to add to the Niven perspective, Protectors evolve into a gender neutral stage once they pass the breeders stage and consume the tree of life root.

Answer (score 6):

In the *Alien Nation* series the Newcomers have three genders.

Come to think of it, more than two sexes is not very plausible.  Finding a suitable mate is challenging enough in a two-sex species. Imagine having to find two suitable mates for a three-sex species, or generally *n-1* suitable mates for an *n*-sex species. Your chances of reproducing will decrease rapidly as *n* increases.

Comment: There were 3? I remember 2 from the TV series: the "woman" carries a fertilized egg (shell and all) for some time, then it is transferred to the "man" who basically carries it in a pouch as it develops into an infant.

Comment: The math isn't much of an objection if (1) the race in question has large broods or (2) some of the genders don't get (or are not able to make) a choice in the matter. A more interesting question is what (if any) biological advantage it might bring.

Comment: @gnovice There were two kinds of males.  One fertilized the egg, and the other, called "binom", provided some sort of "catalyst".

Comment: @dmckee: The biological advantage would be greater variety. If mixing up the genes of two parents is a good idea, then mixing up the genes of three parents must be better. :) But I still think the logistics of getting more than three individual of the right sexes to get together would make it impractical.

Comment: @Dima: It wouldn't be so bad if one or more of those N sexes could change their gender spontaneously to whatever was in short supply, like some frogs apparently can.

Comment: @gnovice: that might help. But then you'd have to work out the biology of being able to change into any one of _n_ sexes. :)

Comment: @Dima - you are not being imaginative enough sociologically. One gender could be subservient to the others (actually IIRC the cogenitors in ST:Ent might have been). They could practice poligamy. They could practice random sexual pairings. They could practice reproductive sets separate from stable matings. And I'm merely listing stuff that is modeled on "normal" human BDSM sociology :)))

Comment: I believe Octavia Butler used a similar concept in [Lilith's Brood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith%27s_Brood) - basically a Male, a Female, and Ooloi a gender that facilitates the reproduction, and can manipulate the genetic material.  Not that much of a stretch, when you consider all the species that basically toss their genetic material to the wind; this gender gathers and uses it, in effect.  (A secondary selector, genetically speaking)

Answer (score 1):

Just to inject a bit of science into this:

[Sex is always well worth its two-fold cost](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.3203) claims to demonstrate why more than 2 sexes are evolutionarily unstable.

[Why two sexes?](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0408006) claims to explain why two sexes has arisen so often in Terran evolution.

Comment: actually, fungi can have up to 11 "genders", but only two mate at a time

Answer (score 0):

The existence of a three-gendered animal species actually forms a plot twist in

> The Hugo and Nebula winning novel [Dreamsnake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamsnake) by Vonda N. McIntyre